# Similarities between two csv files

Tags: python, csv

I'm fairly new to Python and am having a lot of trouble trying to make this program that looks for matches between two csv files. For example, I have two csv files. The first one is called "list" and the second is called "example"

The file "list" contains this in the first row:
leg,knee,thigh,shin,ankle,hip,foot,toe,calf,feet,patella,tibia,fibula

The file "example contains:
Student broke leg yesterday,Student broke arm today,Student hurt thigh today,Student twisted elbow,Student rolled ankle today

So basically if the csv file "example" contains any of the words in the csv file "list" it should output it into a new csv file with the sentences from example but its not.

Here's my code so far: `

```
import csv

   with open("list.csv", "U") as file1, open("example.csv", "rb") as
   file2,open("finalOutput.csv", "wb") as outputfile:
   reader1 = csv.reader(file1,delimiter=';')
   reader2 = csv.reader(file2,delimiter='|')
   writer = csv.writer(outputfile,delimiter='|')

   rows2 = [row for row in reader2]
   for row1 in reader2:
       for row2 in rows2:
           if row1[0] == row2[0]:
               data = [row1[0],row2[0]]
               print data
               writer.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try something like this (assuming you want the whole row printed if any words match a word in the second file. Basically you make the second row a string and then check if any of the words from the first file are in that string. If so, write it out.

```
with open("list.csv", "U") as file1, open("example.csv", "rb") as file2, open("output.csv", "wb+") as file3:
    reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
    reader2 = csv.reader(file2)
    writer = csv.writer(file3)

    reader1_rows = [row for row in reader1]
    reader2_rows = [row for row in reader2]

    for num, row in enumerate(reader1_rows):
        if ([word for word in row if word in ' '.join(reader2_rows[num])]):
            writer.writerow([row, reader2_rows[num]])
```

---

As per your adjusted comment, I believe this one should get you the output you desire:

```
with open("list.csv", "U") as file1, open("example.csv", "rb") as file2, open("output.csv", "wb+") as file3:
    reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
    reader2 = csv.reader(file2)
    writer = csv.writer(file3)

    reader1_rows = [row for row in reader1]
    reader2_rows = [row for row in reader2]

    for num, row in enumerate(reader1_rows):
        for word in reader2_rows[num]:
            for item in row:
                if item in word:
                    writer.writerow([item, word])
```

A bit more 'pythonic' way might be as follows:

```
with open("list.csv", "U") as file1, open("example.csv", "rb") as file2, open("output.csv", "wb+") as file3:
    reader1 = csv.reader(file1)
    reader2 = csv.reader(file2)
    writer = csv.writer(file3)

    reader1_rows = [row for row in reader1]
    reader2_rows = [row for row in reader2]

    for rowA, rowB in zip(reader1_rows, reader2_rows):
        for word in rowA:
            for item in (item for item in rowB if word in item):
                writer.writerow([word, item])
```

---

If you wanted to align all of the data in columns (which for this it sounds like you probably should) and the data looked like this:

```
leg
knee
thigh
shin
ankle
hip
foot
toe
calf
feet
patella
tibia
fibula
```

..and..

```
Student broke leg yesterday
Student broke arm today
Student hurt thigh today
Student twisted elbow
Student rolled ankle today
```

..then you could do this:

```
with open("example.csv") as file1, open("list.csv") as file2, open("output.csv", "wb+") as file3:
    writer = csv.writer(file3)
    key_words = [word.strip() for word in file2.readlines()]
    for row in file1:
        row = row.strip()
        for key in (key for key in key_words if key in row):
            writer.writerow([key, row])
```

Comment: This helped me output something in the file, but not necessarily what I was trying to get. For instance, in "example" there is one example that say "Student broke arm today" But none of those words are in "list" therefore I don't want it printed. If you could help with that, that'd be great!

Comment: Please try my edited answer and let me know if that is the output you are looking for. I am still unsure as to how your files look but I believe (based on your description) that this will cover what you are attempting to accomplish. The output syntax might have to be adjusted slightly.

Comment: Thank You **SOOOO** much! That's exactly what I was looking for but I couldn't quite get it!

Comment: No problem, just glad I could help.

Comment: Row #2 in example would correspond to Row #2 in list. Did you want the one row of list to apply to all rows in example? This is where I'm unsure of how you plan to format these files.

Comment: What if I wanted to have "list" and "example" in column A instead of row 1, how would that work? @Bob

Comment: See my edit, this is why the format for the file is important.

Comment: By far the best help I've ever received! This is perfect. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the structure of your csv files, I think you should not use the csv-reader to load your examples-file and your words...

```
import csv

with open("list.csv", "U") as file1, open("example.csv", "rb") as
    file2,open("finalOutput.csv", "wb") as outputfile:

    writer = csv.writer(outputfile,delimiter='|')

    words = set(file1.read().split(','))

    # examples are split by "," so read the whole file and split it by ","
    examples = file2.read().split(',')

    for word in file1:
        for example in examples:
            # if the word happens to be within the example
            if word in example:
                   # add it to your output file
                   data = [word,example]
                   print data
                   writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: This didn't output anything in the finalOutput.csv file. It was empty

Comment: Ok. @NYJets8778 , what does `words` and `examples` look like if you print it? Maybe the different read-modes could be an issue:`open("list.csv", "U")` and `open("example.csv", "rb")`??

Comment: @Bob actually answered my questions with his code. Thanks